# merging variables in foreach loop

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to merge variables in a foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
// example string for $arr[3] = (1 - 9, 11 - 12, 16 - 17, 20 - 22, 24 - 25, 34 - 37, 39 - 42);

$nice = $arr[3];                     
$arr2 = explode(",", $nice);
foreach ($arr2 as $val1) {
    if (strpos($val1, ' - ') != FALSE) {
        $val1 = trim($val1);
        $str1 = substr($val1, 0, 2);
        $str2 = substr($val1, -2);                          
        $nice = range($str1, $str2);                        
        print_r($nice); 

        foreach ($nice as $nice_neu) {                      
            $nice_fin .= ", " . $nice_neu;                                                        
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this results!

`nice neu:, 35, 36, 41, 42, 35, 36, 41, 42, 41, 42, 41, 42, 35, 36, 38, 39, 35, 36, 41, 42, 1`

`nice neu:, 35, 36, 41, 42, 35, 36, 41, 42, 41, 42, 41, 42, 35, 36, 38, 39, 35, 36, 41, 42, 1, 2`

and so on ...

The result should look like this:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42`

Thank you!

Comment: Try this

$nice = "1 - 9,11 - 12,16 - 17,20 - 22,24 - 25,34 - 37,39 - 42";
$arr2 = explode(",", $nice);
$nice_fin = '';
foreach ($arr2 as $val1) {
    if (strpos($val1, ' - ') != FALSE) {    
        $val1 = trim($val1);
        $str1 = substr($val1, 0, 2);
        $str2 = substr($val1, -2);
        $nice = range($str1, $str2);                        
        foreach ($nice as $nice_neu) {
   if($nice_fin=='')
    $nice_fin = $nice_neu;                                                        
   else
    $nice_fin .= ', '.$nice_neu;
        }
    }
}  
print_r($nice_fin);

Comment: i didn`t get the output that i expected! so i don`t understand why is this thread marked as duplicate. I am asking another question!

Comment: thanks baddy! it works like a charme!